# JMS TextMessage not recognizing CR LF

Tags: java, jms, java-io, carriage-return, linefeed

It appears to me like JMS [TextMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) containing `Java.lang.String` isn't recognizing `\r\n` as line-break but instead treating the CR LF as part of input on a Windows machine.

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
      String text = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
      String line=null;
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text));      
      for(line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
           System.out.println(line);
      }
      catch (JMSException e) {
             System.err.println( "Error processing message: " + e.getMessage() );
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can anyone provide any input and /or recommednations around the same.

Comment: plz add the exception message

Comment: There is no exception message but everything gets printed on one line, even \r\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason could be that it is not sent properly from the source system. I would look there to see what can be done next. Most languages offer cross-platform EOL constant's which might come in handy. For instance, `Ruby` has four:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'English'; test = "One"+ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
=> "One\n"
irb(main):003:0> test1 = "One" + $/
=> "One\n"
irb(main):004:0> test2 = "One"+$-0
=> "One\n"
irb(main):005:0> require 'English';test3="One"+$RS
=> "One\n"
irb(main):006:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear from your question, but it sounds like the string is read correctly on *input*, but it is not being formatted correctly by the `println` *output*.

Control characters like line-feeds and and carriage returns are just like any other character in a string.  What makes them different is how they are *interpreted* by the output device, lie a terminal program (e.g. linux terminal, putty, etc.) or the windows command prompt.

If you are printing this string to a destination that does not interpret these characters correctly, you may not see proper formatting even if the string data is correct.  For example some IDE's output windows do not correctly format certain control characters, so you'll see different formatting in your IDE than you would see in an actual terminal.

Comment: Am using Eclipse IDE & I tested on a Java String which does output the String (separated by CRLF) on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 String text = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
 if(text!=null)
     text=text.replaceAll("\r\n","");
```